# Get column headers dynamically from json in Power Automate

Tags: json, power-automate

I have a json which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "TimePeriod": "12/12/23 - 12/26/23",
    "ResourceName": "rob brien",
    "TimesheetStatus": "Submitted",
    "SubmittedBy": "rob brien",
    "LastModified": "12/12/23 7:12 AM",
    "InvestmentTasks": [
      {
        "InvestmentID": "PRO13796",
        "Investment": "Credit Risk Regulatory ",
        "Description": "A3-Dev/Build",
        "Hours": {
          "12/12": 9,
          "12/13": 9,
          "12/14": 9,
          "12/15": 9,
          "12/16": 9,
          "12/17": 0,
          "12/18": 9,
          "12/19": 9,
          "12/20": 9,
          "12/21": 0,
          "12/22": 9,
          "12/23": 9,
          "12/24": 9,
          "12/25": 9,
          "12/26": 9,
          "Total": 99
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, I'm manually mapping the headers in excel in "add a row into table" step (in Power Automate).

Now the issue arrives with dates which are under "Hours" object.

Dates may change either it can increase or decrease or it can be from a different month like 11/1,11/2,11/26 and  can get any no of days from a month.

How can I dynamically get these date column headers?

I have come across an article using xpath function:[https://mytrial365.com/2023/07/13/discovering-json-value-using-a-dynamic-key-in-power-automate/#:~:text=Discovering%20JSON%20Value%20Using%20a%20Dynamic%20Key%20in%20Power%20Automate,-Kailash%20Ramachandran%20Power&text=Power%20Automate%20offers%20several%20options,outputs%20for%20the%20parsed%20properties](https://mytrial365.com/2023/07/13/discovering-json-value-using-a-dynamic-key-in-power-automate/#:%7E:text=Discovering%20JSON%20Value%20Using%20a%20Dynamic%20Key%20in%20Power%20Automate,-Kailash%20Ramachandran%20Power&text=Power%20Automate%20offers%20several%20options,outputs%20for%20the%20parsed%20properties).

[image]

Xpath Step :xpath(xml(body('Parse_JSON_Hours')), '/Hours/*')

APPLY TO EACH 2 STEP: passing the output of xpath

EACH ITEM: xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')

**Error**: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'xpath' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'JSON root object has multiple properties. The root object must have a single property in order to create a valid XML document. Consider specifying a DeserializeRootElementName. Path 'outputs.body.Sat_12_2

I need to get dates header dynamically as no of days are not fixed or it can be for a different month .
Expected output:

```
12/12   12/13
9       9    

   so on...
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. An XML document needs a root element. And your `Parse JSON Hours` is returning:

```json
{
  "12/12": 9,
  ...
  "Total": 99
}
```

Which doesn't have one root property.

Update your `xpath` step to:

```
xpath(
  xml(json(
    concat('{"Hours:', string(body('Parse_JSON_Hours')), '}')
  )),
  '/Hours/*'
)
```

And that should resolve the error.

**BUT** XML Element names cannot start with a digit and as a result it will fetch the names encoded. Time for Plan B.

---

**Plan B**

Rename your `xpath` step to `Obj2Array`, and then update it to:

```
json(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
    concat('[', string( body('Parse_JSON_Hours') ), ']' ),
  ':', '"value":'),
  ',', '},{"name":'),
  '""', '","'),
  '[{', '[{"name":')
)
```

This will result in an array of this format:

```json
[
  { "name": "12/12", "value": 9 },
  { "name": "12/13", "value": 9 },
  { ... }
]
```

Then check your `Apply to each 2` step is using `outputs('Obj2Array')`.

Finally, in your loop, you can use:

```
item()?['name']
```

and

```
item()?['value']
```

Comment: Hi Sam Nseir , Thank you for your time. It is working now .I'm able to get values using xpath(item(), 'string(/*)') but I'm not able to get the keys .I have tried using xpath(item(), 'Hours(/*)') or xpath(item(), 'names(/*)') or xpath(item(), '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$') but all these options are not working. How can I get the headers?

Comment: `xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')`

Comment: Hi @Sam Nseir, I tried using - xpath(item(), 'name(/*)') also but output from this is "root" and 
_x0031_2_x002F_14 , _x0031_2_x002F_15, _x0031_2_x002F_16, Keys are not getting correctly fetched from this. However only 1 key got picket up i.e. "Total".

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, see updated answer above - 2nd part!

Comment: Hi Sam ,It is working now, keys and values are getting pulled .Thank you for your time. If there is any article or source where I can learn the trick which you mentioned in obj2array step then please do share , it will of great help to me .Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is for you to get what you need is to use the **Advanced Data Operations** connector and the **Json Properties to Name Value Pair Array** operation.

https://statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/

It will produce this output which you can then loop through and do what you need with ...

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "InvestmentTasks",
    "propertyType": "Array",
    "propertyValue": [
      [
        {
          "propertyName": "Description",
          "propertyType": "String",
          "propertyValue": "A3-Dev/Build"
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Hours",
          "propertyType": "Object",
          "propertyValue": [
            {
              "propertyName": "12/12",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/13",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/14",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/15",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/16",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/17",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 0
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/18",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/19",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/20",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/21",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 0
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/22",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/23",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/24",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/25",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "12/26",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 9
            },
            {
              "propertyName": "Total",
              "propertyType": "Integer",
              "propertyValue": 99
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Investment",
          "propertyType": "String",
          "propertyValue": "Credit Risk Regulatory "
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "InvestmentID",
          "propertyType": "String",
          "propertyValue": "PRO13796"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "LastModified",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "12/12/23 7:12 AM"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "ResourceName",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "rob brien"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "SubmittedBy",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "rob brien"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "TimePeriod",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "12/12/23 - 12/26/23"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "TimesheetStatus",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "Submitted"
  }
]
```

... the only caveat is that it takes an object, not an array so you can do it for the first row in your dataset and go from there.

For your data set, using the XML approach may be a little troublesome, if I convert your JSON to XML, I get this ...

```
<root>
    <InvestmentTasks>
        <Description>A3-Dev/Build</Description>
        <Hours>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_12>9</_x0031_2_x002F_12>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_13>9</_x0031_2_x002F_13>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_14>9</_x0031_2_x002F_14>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_15>9</_x0031_2_x002F_15>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_16>9</_x0031_2_x002F_16>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_17>0</_x0031_2_x002F_17>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_18>9</_x0031_2_x002F_18>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_19>9</_x0031_2_x002F_19>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_20>9</_x0031_2_x002F_20>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_21>0</_x0031_2_x002F_21>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_22>9</_x0031_2_x002F_22>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_23>9</_x0031_2_x002F_23>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_24>9</_x0031_2_x002F_24>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_25>9</_x0031_2_x002F_25>
            <_x0031_2_x002F_26>9</_x0031_2_x002F_26>
            <Total>99</Total>
        </Hours>
        <Investment>Credit Risk Regulatory</Investment>
        <InvestmentID>PRO13796</InvestmentID>
    </InvestmentTasks>
    <LastModified>12/12/23 7:12 AM</LastModified>
    <ResourceName>rob brien</ResourceName>
    <SubmittedBy>rob brien</SubmittedBy>
    <TimePeriod>12/12/23 - 12/26/23</TimePeriod>
    <TimesheetStatus>Submitted</TimesheetStatus>
</root>
```

... and as you can see, the slashes don't really translate too well.

To answer your question though, when converting to XML, you'll need to use this expression ...

```
xml(json(concat('{ "root": ', variables('Data'), ' }')))
```

... obviously replacing the `variables('Data')` part with your own JSON object.